# How to calculate total convertion duration before converting with FFMPEG in nodeJS

Tags: node.js, ffmpeg

With FFMPEG in nodeJS,

I would like to convert a video with FFMPEG.

How can I calculate total convertion duration before processing the conversion ?

Example : How long time a 1 Go AVI movie takes to be converted in MKV ?

Answer (score 0):

You can't know in advance the exact amount of time needed for executing the conversion.

If you know the total number of frames of the target file you can use this formula:

`T_full_conversion_time = T_elapsed * T_total_frame_count/ T_converted_frames`

You can use  `T_full_conversion_time` and `T_elapsed` and estimate the remaining time.

Comment: Ok, and can I know in advance the exact amount of frames of the source file ?